# What happens if a user has 2 accounts that vote on each others posts?

Tags: support, voting, voting-fraud, sock-puppets

What if a user creates two logins and posts questions and answers by themselves and then uses the second account to vote on those questions and answers?

Is this case is handled or not? It helps people obtain a good reputation that was not truly given by the community.

Comment: That's called sock puppeting, and the system and the moderators take care of it as much as possible.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/what-happens-when-vote-fraud-gets-past-the-script

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Such behaviour is considered voting fraud, and moderators will remove the extra account (called a *sockpuppet*) if found out. All such votes will be nullified. Generally, the perpetrating account will be put on a temporary account suspension.

If you see evidence of such accounts, flag one of the posts for moderator attention (pick the *Other* option) and explain the situation. They'll take it from there. Don't accuse the accounts in comments to the posts, you *could* have misunderstood something.

Moderators have tools to detect such behaviour as well, but help from the community is always appreciated.

Comment: How do you report people with 2 accounts?

Comment: @Pete: flag one of their posts for moderator attention, explain what you think is going on and what the other account would be.