# Found a weird change in reputation history. Seems like Parallel Serial voting

Tags: support

I suddenly noticed a weird change in my reputation history. It goes -42. First I think any of the question which I answered may be deleted or something.

But when I checked my reputation history, it seems like a **Parallel Serial Voting**

[image]

Comment: As always, wait 24 hours for the serial voting reversal script to run.

Comment: Given the timestamps of the votes this is most likely the result of a script. Somebody must really like you to put all that effort into it.

Comment: although these are likely to be [reverted as usual](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252271/839601) this case seems more troubling than it typically is suggesting that there could be a user with 2-3 sock puppets all having over 125 rep (and not hesitating to use these socks in quite a slippery way)

Comment: @Floern reversed votes would be labelled as such. These do look like down-votes.

Comment: That is the exact case I think. A user may have 3 sock puppets and downvoted. I hope some mod may look into this issue

Comment: @ChrisF I didn't think this is 3 different users. Can you check whether it is a sock puppetry?

Comment: @SagarV it would have to be separate accounts, a single account can't down-vote the same post more than once.

Comment: @ChrisF: That's why he's saying it could be socks.

Comment: @ChrisF I meant somebody wrote a script to cast these votes. I doubt they were cast by hand.

Comment: @Floern - ah, sorry. I thought you were talking about the vote reversal scripts.

Comment: I think someone looked into this. The series voting is reversed. Thanks for the quick support

Comment: I am just joking brother. I won't like to participate in a down vote war.

Comment: I deleted it because it is being put on hold as off topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To close this out, yes, you were targeted with downvotes by a user and their sock puppets. These have been invalidated and the user dealt with.

In the future, I recommend using a custom moderator flag and explaining the situation. We'll be able to look into it and take the appropriate action.

Comment: Yes I saw. He is suspended till _Jul 21 at 16:40._

Comment: current duplicate doesn't look sufficient: it addresses the vote-reversal part of the question but per my reading says nothing about sock puppets reporting. The missing part seems to be covered in [How can I ask a moderator to investigate a potential puppet account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288071/839601) Please consider adding it as a second duplicate