# How long it will take to revert serial up/down votes?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

1. Suspected a serial voting because votes came with less than a minute!
2. Flagged it to a moderator
3. output -> *helpful - I have escalated this to the CMs.*  and moderator did his job, grateful for that.

After the mod's reply the flagged post in my recent inbox was displayed as `+1` instead of `-2`, yet when check the questions that previous down votes were there.

I don't know what is CM means and it took any action or not! 
This happened in 25th Feb votes came on 23rd yet it didn't get revert.

I know lot of people flag and mods gets busy and it's a time taking task so not asking to investigate .

My questions are,

1. How long can it take to CM s to revert ? [every night around 03:00 UTC?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)
2. Even if it(CM) reject mods request will I get any notification?
3. Or after a certain time do I need to [contact](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) 
   Help Center?
4. Or should I just let it go like [What happens when vote fraud gets past the script?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/what-happens-when-vote-fraud-gets-past-the-script)

**Edit** : If you already flagged your issue and if its helpful & escalated trust on CM guys sit back and relax.It takes some time yet you will get it! I got it now.

[image]

Comment: Really depends. They handled it pretty quickly in my case (a few days on all occassions, IIRC). The 03:00 UTC time is only when the script runs.

Comment: "CM" stands for Community Manager. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do

Comment: @S.L. Barth  all right, just curious! :) Thanks for the info at legoscia

Comment: @Charuක it's in the queue - so don't worry about it - but please don't double up the work by contacting the CM team outside the flag you've used which a mod escalated to the team. If the CM team after investigation agree that votes need invalidation, then you'll probably notice voting corrections on your account. Apart from that, generally they'll be no notice/feedback on the outcome of your query.

Comment: @Jon Clements roger that! Nope I didn't flagged/sent a message again just asked to confirm and your comment makes me happy.okay sit back and relax Charuක :D

Comment: @Charuක if it's really serial voting, it's reversed. My flag took only one week to be processed (3 downvotes on questions, petty thief :))